# After migration to Angular 15, context was removed from test.ts

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

In our project in order to reduce the quantity of running tests and during development run the specific tests only for certain file we used our own script with this technique:

[image: An answer on StackOverflow with a score of 124. The body of the answer details how to replace the wildcard matcher for tests with a matcher that will only match a single test.]

However after the migration to Angular 15, this 'context' stuff was removed from test.ts file.

Is there a way to still use the same technique in Angular 15?

I tried to return 'context' to the test.ts with no success.

Answer (score 6):

##### Simple solution: just remove the call to `require.context`

I just faced the same problem, converting an app from Angular 14 to 15, and it turns out the solution is even simpler: just delete the two lines at the bottom of `src/test.ts`. The call to `require.context()` is no longer needed.

I used to have

```
const context = require.context("./", true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

at the end of `src/test.ts`, but now I have deleted those two lines and my tests all run just like they used to with Angular 14.

I could not find proper documentation for this change (that's why I landed on this question in the first place) but my assumption is that Karma now automatically finds all the `*.spec.ts` files and we no longer need to direct it to do so.

##### Narrow the test suites with `"include"`

The `"include"` property, added under `"test":`/`"options":`, is only needed if you want to restrict the list of spec files to run.

So, according to my tests, configuring `angular.json` like this:

```
   "test": {
     "options": {
        "include": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
        ...
     },
     ...
```

or the same without `"include"`, all spec files are exercised.

But configuring `angular.json` like this:

```
   "test": {
     "options": {
        "include": ["**/app.component.spec.ts"],
        ...
     },
     ...
```

only spec files call `app.component.spec.ts` actually get exercised.

I don't know why you'd want to restrict which spec files are exercised, but I think it's worth documenting this here to understand what is going on.

Comment: I've removed the test.ts file and its reference in angular.json ("main"). But now specs are saying:   `Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing`. And that's something that's normally addressed by test.ts

Comment: You need to add `"zone.js"` and `"zone.js/testing"` to the `polyfills` array in `options` in `test`, like `"test": { "options": { "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"] } }`

Answer (score 5):

test.ts file is no longer generated by angular, and the property `main` used to link the file is no longer allowed in angular.json, you can use the include property in angular.json to add patterns or file name

```json
"test": {
  ...
  "options": {
    "include": [
      "**/app.component.spec.ts"
    ]
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it got me to a working solution, which I just documented in a second answer here.

Comment: I could just be unaware of an alternative configuration. But I think the “include” needs to be inside of an “options” object - as @someone demonstrated in their separate answer

Comment: yes, include needs to be inside options

Answer (score 2):

Because these are jasmine tests, another approach to running specific tests during development is to **f**orce just those to run:

1. Change `describe(…)` to `fdescribe(…)` (and/or `it(…)` to `fit(…)`) for the specific specs you are working on. Only these will be run.
2. Get them working.
3. Change `fdescribe(…)`/`fit(…)` back to `describe(…)`/`it(…)`. All the specs will run again.

There may be similar functionality for other testing frameworks.

Note: Similarly, specs can be e**x**cluded with `xdescribe(…)` and `xit(…)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is not anymore allowed ( In the schema.json of the angular.json it is still allowed ) but when I add this as main.ts it works for me and I don't get errors that a directive or component is not recognized ( I get errors when I remove test.ts )

```
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

in the angular.json I use:

```
        "main": "projects/mijn-svb/src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "zone.js/testing"
        ],
        "karmaConfig": "projects/mijn-svb/karma.conf.js",
```

don't forget to add the test.ts to your tsconfig.spec.json

```
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts"
  ],
```